# Singularity extraction: $\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{(x-.3)^2+y^2}}$

Tags: definite-integrals, singularity, singular-values, singularity-theory

$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{(x-.3)^2+y^2}}$ has the following physical meaning:
it is the potential of the uniform surface source distributed on a square $|x|,|y|<1$ observed at a point $O=(0.3,0)$. Obviously the point $O$ is a singular point.

I could evaluate the following integrals using WOLFARM ALPHA:
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{0.3}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{(x-.3)^2+y^2}}=3.9989$$
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{0.3}^{1}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{(x-.3)^2+y^2}}=2.9216$$
The question is is it allowable to add up the results obove to conclude the following in spite of the above mentioned singularity?
$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{(x-.3)^2+y^2}}=3.9989+2.9216=6.9205$$
Any other way to solve?

Comment: Polar coordinates tells you that the improper *double*  integral $\iint_D 1/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dA$ converges just fine.